# VDJ sequencing in mice, DNA or RNA?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, immunology, pcr

I am wondering if anyone who is well versed with VDJ sequencing for TCR repertoire analysis (specifically CDR3) would know if DNA or RNA is a better starting material? We are looking at the effects of radiation therapy on immune system of mice. Thanks

Comment: DNA is typically easier to work with. Just make sure the cells you're working with have actually matured enough and undergone VDJ recombination.

Comment: I agree with @MattDMo Colleagues next door have done this with single sorted cells which where sequenced afterwards.

Comment: @MattDMo @Chris♦ how do you suggest one makes sure T cells have matured and undergone VDJ recombination?? I have looked at literature and seen one study that looked at clonal expansion 22 days after radiation exposure but they did not say why. Also, I have read that RNA is better to use than DNA since DNA won’t give you the antigen specificity you can see with mRNA expression. I have also seen that DNA can only show you the possible combinations of VDJ you could get as mRNA shows you the ones you did get, in real time.

Comment: I suggest you spend some time looking at the details of somatic recombination. Early during maturation, the V, (D,) J, and C protogenes recombine in the DNA to form the first version of the recombined TCR $\alpha/\gamma$ and $\beta/\delta$ chains (different protogenes combine in different ways in the different chains). These recombined sequences are then transcribed as mRNA - to my knowledge the protogenes are never transcribed. So, mRNA sequences should match DNA sequences.

Comment: The reason I gave my caveat is because if you just take a whole thymus and do single-cell sequencing, you'll also get immature T cells that haven't undergone recombination. Instead, I would use either blood-derived cells, or sort thymocytes using a marker that is expressed after recombination. I would choose blood, because some of the recombined thymocytes will die during further maturation, and probably shouldn't be included in your measurements of TCR diversity.